# find limit distribution by using central limit theorem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution

$$x_1,...,x_n \sim \text{uniform (0,1)}$$

$$Y_n=\sum_i^n X_i$$

I want to find limit distribution by using central limit theorem.

$E(Y_n)=n/2$ and $V(Y_n)=n/12$

And Moment generating function $M_{Yn }(t)= (\frac{e^t-1}{t})^n$

What I did is the following. (Sorry for photo, but It is too hard to write such a long solution with latex for me)

[image]
[image]

I stack here.  What is the distribution of Yn? If my solution is false, ignore it and solve correctly please

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find the limit distribution of? The $Y_n$ are not really well-behaved, but for example $Y_n/n$ is. And are you trying to prove CLT in this case, or are you just expected to apply it?

Comment: I want to show that Yn converges to standard normal distribution or another distribution(which distribution?) by using CLT's proof. @AndréNicolas

Comment: $Y_n$ does not really converge to anything, the means go to $\infty$. The random variables $Y_n/n$ converge to a normal mean $1/2$, variance $1/12$. To do this you can quote CLT, or look at the behaviour of the mgf of $Y_n/n$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's $Y_n/n$ means $\bar {Y_n}$ ? I can show $\bar{Y_n} \to N(1/2, 1/12)$ as $n \to \infty$.  Right? Well what is the moment generatinf function of $Y_n/n $?

Comment: You probably know, or can look up, the mgf of an independent sum, if you know the mgf of the summands, also the mgf of $cY$ if you know the mgf of $Y$.   And yes, $\frac{Y_n}{n}$ is often called $\bar{Y}_n$.

Comment: Actually, $Y_n/n$ converges to a Dirac mass at $1/2$ (not to a nondegenerate normal) but indeed $Z_n=3(2Y_n-n)/\sqrt{n}$ converges to a standard normal. To prove both properties, use your computation of $M_{Y_n}(t)$, for example to show that $M_{Z_n}(t)\to e^{t^2/2}$. The expansions $e^u=1+u+u^2/2+u^3/6+o(u^3)$ and $\log(1+u)=u-u^2/2+o(u^2)$ when $u\to0$ will be required.

Comment: *Please replace the only $3$ by $\sqrt{3}$ in my previous comment.

Comment: @Did i did what you said.. but Zn converges to $exp(3t^2/2)\sim N(0, 3/2)$

Comment: @did if you want, i can send my solution.